# solving matrix to echelon form

Tags: matrices

I am trying to solve this matrix to change the k in the 2nd row to a 0, and the 1 in the 2nd row to also a 0 however I am a bit stuck, I can't think of what row ops to use because the k's can't really be turned into numbers?

\begin{matrix}
    1 & k : 1  \\
    k & 1  : 1 \\
    \end{matrix}

Comment: First, from $\left[\begin{array}{rr|r}
1 & k & 1 \\
k & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]$, perform $\color{blue}{R_2 \to R_2 - kR_1}$. Try and go from there. Note that you are allowed to use $k$ or things involving $k$ as a scalar multiple for these row operations. Also, why do you want the second row of the left-hand matrix to become all $0$'s? As long as you can make the $k$ in the second row become $0$, you will have achieved row echelon form (don't require the $1$ in the second row to be $0$).

Comment: oh thanks. I thought that the 1 had to be 0? I might be wrong. thansk though